# Merge Two Columns from Two Tables while Join, and aggregate function are used

Tags: postgresql, join, merge

I have two tables. One is Cost_Table, the other is Hire_Table.

The layout of **Cost_Table** is shown as below:

```
 sitename   cost   impressions  deliverydate
  Yahoo     100      10000       2016-01-01
  Yahoo     200      20000       2016-01-02
  Google    200      30000       2016-01-02
  Google    500      50000       2016-01-03
```

The layout of **Hire_Table** is shown as below:

```
 site      Hiredate
 Yahoo    2016-03-01
 Yahoo    2016-04-02
 Yahoo    2016-04-28
 Bing     2016-03-01
 Bing     2014-06-01
```

I joined two table, my code is listed below:

```
 select hire.site, cost.mediaspend,cost.impression,count(hire.site) as hires from Hire_Table Hire

 Full Join

(select sitename, sum(cost) as mediaspend, sum(impressions) as impression from Cost_Table
 where deliverydate between '2016-01-01' and '2016-07-31'
 group by sitename)  cost  

 on hire.site=cost.sitename

 group by hire.site, cost.mediaspend,cost.impression
```

The result is:

```
 sitename   mediaspend   impression   hires
  Yahoo       300          30000        3
  Bing        --            --          2
```

However, this doesn't give me the **sitename** which is not in the **Hire_Table**, such as **Google**. I tried to use **Coalesce**, but it didn't change the result either. **Coalesce(cost.sitename,hire.site)**

I saw some posts mentioned Union function. I think it may not work on my sample, as I want to extract different contents from two tables. Any lights will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `FULL JOIN`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza  I used Left Join as the beginning, but it didn't work. And then I used Full Join instead, because I want to return the Site info from both the left and the right table. However, it still didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT allSites.sitename, costs.mediaspend,  costs.impressions, Hires.hires
FROM (SELECT sitename FROM Cost_Table 
      UNION
      SELECT site     FROM Hire_Table) as allSites
LEFT JOIN (SELECT sitename,                
                  SUM(cost) as mediaspend,
                  SUM(impressions) as impressions
           FROM Cost_Table
           GROUP BY sitename) costs
  ON allSites.sitename = costs.sitename
LEFT JOIN (SELECT site,                
                  COUNT(Hiredate) as hires
           FROM Hire_Table 
           GROUP BY site) Hires
  ON allSites.sitename = Hires.site
```

Comment: This is helpful. A fresh and flexible thinking for me!